# SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I am using JQuery Zoomer and in place of larg Image path i am giving this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready
        $('img.zoomer_panel').addpowerzoom({
        defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2,5],  
        largeimage: "/editor.images/images/Ranches/bb-brooks-ranch/BB-Brook-North-Map.jpg",
        magnifiersize: [100,100] //<--no comma following last option!
    }) /**/
})
</script>
```

And it gives me this ERROR

> **SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a
>
>   largeimage: /editor.images/images/Ranches/bb-brooks-ranch/BB-Brook-North-Map.jpg**

Please tell me what i am doing WRONG :(

Comment: Sounds like you're `eval`ing some data that contains an invalid expression.